# Count the number of ones in a binary representation of an integer (MASM)

Tags: assembly, masm

So I'm pretty new to assembly language and I was hoping I could get some help. I'm trying to count the number of ones in a binary representation of an integer. I believe what I'm supposed to is shift the register where I have my input number 32 times and increment each time I come across a 1. I should jump should it not be a 1 to avoid incrementing ebx. I'm still a beginner so I'm still learning the MASM syntax but here is what I have so far:

```
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ecx, 32

shifting:
    shl eax, 1
    jc $+2
    inc ebx
    loop shifting
```

Comment: Does it work? Do you want to improve it in some way? (you should ask a question, not just describe what you did)

Comment: Why is this tagged 'c'?

Comment: No its not working, when I test out the code it gives a number much higher then the number of 1s in the binary representation. I'm pretty sure my thought process is correct but the actual programming of it is what's giving me trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Using `$+2` is not recommended, use a label. Note that `jc $+2` doesn't do anything because the instruction itself is 2 bytes long so it just continues on in either case. Also, you are skipping incrementing the counter when the bit is set, so you would be counting the zero bits. Correct code could look like:

```
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ecx, 32

shifting:
    shl eax, 1
    jnc skip_inc
    inc ebx
skip_inc:
    loop shifting
```

Comment: Another approach would involve `adc ebx, 0`. Still another approach would involve `popcnt` (newer processors only).

Comment: Yeah, there was another answer here that detailed those. Anyway, the OP probably wants to stick to his own algorithm, just fix the code.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to point out that "there's more than one way to skin a cat". (the cat doesn't like any of 'em.)